# Efficient algorithm to find a set of integers, if we are told closest lower or equal number to a number we tell

Tags: algorithm, search, integer, set

Imagine that we have a set of integers. We don't know it, the only thing we know is that every number lies in interval [0, MAX), and, obviously, numbers do not repeat. Then, we need to find a set. We are allowed to name an integer, and then we are told a number in set, which is less or equal than number we've chosen and is closest to it. Our purpose is to find a set with minimal number of tries.

For example, let us have a set [0, 7, 8, 1000], and MAX==10000. Let TRY be the function we can use. Then TRY(4)==0, TRY(7)==7, TRY(8)==8, TRY(555)==8 and TRY(7777)==1000. We then must get sure that we didn't miss a number, so we must try many other numbers.

The question is: what is the most efficient algorithm to find the set? Trying every number in interval is obviously bad. Maybe we should try a binary-search-like algorithm which excludes sets, which are guaranteed to have no numbers (TRY(7777)==1000, so no numbers in (1000, 7777]). Algorithm with minimal number of tries would be the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding something here, but it seems to me you'll just start at `MAX`, thus recieving the largest number in the set. Then just continue guessing at the recieved number - 1 until no more numbers remain, or 0 is reached. This would require one guess per number.

Right?

Comment: Lol, it's really so! With this rules the answer your answer is really the obvious one. Maybe the reason I failed in not seeing it is that I oversimplified the problem i've got (in which we could not directly try numbers, but must computate complex, yet monotonous function TRY). Anyway, in this terms your solution is perfectly right.